# User capability of create page/new page

Tags: pages, user-roles, capabilities

I am working with the Role and Capabilities API for the first time today and making use of the the excellent [Members plugin](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin). Having tinkered around for some time I notice that the "edit pages" capability does two things:

1. Allow the user to create a new page
2. Allow the user to edit existing pages

I am trying to split this capability into two. I want my user to:

1. Not be able to create any new pages
2. Allow the user to edit existing pages

I am looking to write some code for my theme that allows this to happen. I can create a new capability very easily. The challenge is then getting WordPress to respond accordingly to it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed a problem. A dedicated 'create_posts' capability is planed:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16714

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is a shame this is not available now. As a temporary solution I have filtered the relevant menus from the admin menu and hidden certain buttons with CSS. Not ideal but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have been researching this for a while, came up with the following hack.
In wp-admin/new_post.php add the following, after the wp_die line:

```
wp_die( __('Invalid post type') );
```

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) and $post_type == 'page') {
    echo "To create new pages please ask site admin";
    exit;
} //if user is not admin, a warning is issued and script terminated
```

then in wp-admin/menu, add a conditional for showing the add page submenu in admin. The line is normally there but not included within the if statement

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) { //if user is admin, show submenu for creating new pages, else no luck
   $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'][10] = array( _x('Add New', 'page'), get_post_type_object( 'page' )->cap->create_posts, 'post-new.php?post_type=page' );
}
```

I still have to figure out how to remove the add new button in the edit pages, however users with publish rights can now edit existing pages but not create new pages. If they press the new page button they get a warning and cannot proceed further. Posts are not affected. The same code could easily be applied to prevent the creation of new posts aswell with just little editing.

Hope this helps - Ackab

Comment: This is wrong. It will break after the next WordPress update.

Comment: toscho will the next release include a create posts capability? Anyway this works for what I need, in the current version. Do you have a better/cleaner way to do it in the current version?

Comment: If you read the ticket @scribu linked to, you will see this capability is already in WordPress 3.5.

Comment: toscho I am using role scoper, and cannot see a way to prevent a user from creating new pages. If I assign publish rights, then he can create new pages. Do you have an hint as to how I block a role from creating new pages with the now available capability. Just a little pointer would be great thanks

Comment: `remove_cap( $role, $cap )`

Comment: Toscho, thanks for your patience, I am learning and I am a beginner with WP. I tried to create a simple plugin. The plugin works with some test code, but if I add:
remove_cap('author','create_posts'); WP crashes. Any hint? Thank you